# Keras ModelCheckpoint monitor multiple values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-2

I want to use Keras ModelCheckpoint callback to monitor several parameters ( I have a multi-task network). Is it possible with just one callback ? Or do I need to do that in many callbacks ??

The ckechpoint creation :

```python
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpoints/weights-{epoch:02d}.hdf5', monitor='val_O1_categorical_accuracy' , verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

The second parameter I want to monitor : `val_O2_categorical_accuracy`

Doing that in a list will not work. i.e.

```python
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpoints/weights-{epoch:02d}.hdf5', monitor=['val_O1_categorical_accuracy','val_O2_categorical_accuracy'] , verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you will have to do it in separate instances. Think about what is happening here -

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpoints/weights-{epoch:02d}.hdf5', monitor='val_O1_categorical_accuracy' , verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

When you are saving a model by monitoring `val_O1_categorical_accuracy`, here is what it will do in pseudocode -

```
for each epoch:
    check the val_O1_categorical_accuracy after updating weights
    if this metric is better in this epoch than the previous ones:
        save the model
    else
        pass
```

So really specifying multiple `monitor` is out of scope. In this case it has to be an either/or choice as based on a `monitor` metric only one model among other conflicting models can be the best one.

Comment: Okay thank you, I think I will add a second metric that computes the mean of the two losses,

Comment: yes that's a good call. I have never played with the `monitor` param. May be it does support `callable`. Anyway if your query is resolved please mark as answer so that others searching for something similar will be able to find the help. Otherwise, post the answer yourself in case you have figured it out and mark it